# Proof behind inertia increases with mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, inertia

My book starts off by giving an example that if we kick a football it flies away but if we kick a stone of the same size with equal force then it stays at rest. It says that from this series of events we may conclude that inertia increases with mass.

But can't there be several other reasons why the stone didn't move?

For example considering the fact that the stone has greater mass, maybe when we kick the stone with the same amount of force used to kick the football, the stone does start to move with lesser acceleration than the football but is subsequently stopped by friction?

On top of that since the stone weighs more, the friction is also more. Maybe that stops from it flying away?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are completely right: the stone, due to its higher inertia (because of its higher mass), accelerates less but is still moving. That’s the essence of $F=ma$. So the example in your book is indeed not accurate.

An accurate experiment would take place in more controlled context, e.g. letting the probes of different mass hang from a long string. That’s what Newton did AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks!  So the stone accelerates less due to higher mass or higher inertia? Or is it the same thing in this context?

Comment: That’s the point! The fact the the gravitational mass (the property of mass that gives rise to the gravitational force) and the inertial mass (the property of mass that gives rise to the resistance against acceleration) result in *exactly equal* opposite effects. This was quite mysterious (until Einstein came along) and is the ultimate reason why all bodies, irrespective of their mass, fall with the same acceleration (when friction is eliminated from the experiment).

Comment: I kindly ask the downvoter to edit my answer, give a comment or write an own answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you had taken a 1000 kg football then if you kicked it, would it move? The answer is I don't know until you tell me how much force you had done on that object.. Assume there's no friction (which we usually assume always in Newtonian mechanics, we rarely work with friction in newtonian mechanics but I will show what will happen if there was force) and you may know the following equation from your elementary school.

$$F=ma \tag{2}$$
And $$F=mg \tag{1}$$
We had taken a football which is 1000 kg, Let's put the value in equation 1.

$$F=1000 \mathrm kg \cdot 9.8 \mathrm ms^{-2}=9800 \mathrm N \tag{3}$$

If you apply 9800 N or more than that force then the ball will move otherwise the ball won’t. The same thing was happening with your example. Your ball's initial force (gravitational force) was less stone's that's why the ball moved easily but not stone.

What will happen if there was frictional force?

We calculated in 3rd equation that gravitational force of a random ball is 9800 N. Now assume frictional force on that field was 10 N. Since frictional force is stopping the ball also then it will add on ball's force, if you aren’t interested to do that then frictional force will subtract from force which you applied.

$$F_{ball}=9800 N + 10 N=9810 N$$

Now you must apply more than or equal to 9810 N force.